# Laravel orderBy data is shuffling when putting in table

Tags: laravel, datatable

I'm using laravel orderby desc so that i can see the latest data. But when i put it on table using datatable it's not desc, but shuffled.

This is the query from the controller

```
$jobs['jobs'] = jobs::where('isArchive', '0')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

This is the result when i return it and as you can see, the orderBy is working properly.

[image]

And this is the blade where i put the data. As you can see it's asc but only because we only have 3 data. but when we have a lot of data, it's shuffling
[image]

View Code:

```
<table id="jobTable" class="table datatable table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($jobs['jobs'] as $job)
    <tr>
        <td>  {{ $job['title'] }} </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <button onclick=" job_id={{ $job['id'] }}; chooseUser({{$job['id']}});" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#encodeModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm faa-vertical animated-hover faa-slow"><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='Assign Recruitment Associate for {{ $job['title'] }}' class="fa fa-users" id="btn-view-applied"></span></button>

            <button onclick="viewApplied('{{$job['id']}}','{{$job['title']}}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-applied-jobs" class="btn btn-info btn-sm faa-vertical animated-hover faa-slow"><span data-toggle='tooltip' title='View Applicants That Applied in {{ $job['title'] }}' class="fa fa-check-square-o" id="btn-view-applied"></span></button>

            <a href=" {{ route('jobs.edit', $job['id']) }}  " class="btn btn-success btn-sm faa-tada animated-hover faa-fast"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>

            <button onclick="thisArchive('{{route('jobs.archive', $job->id)}}', '{{$job->title}} job')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archiveModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm faa-ring animated-hover faa-slow"><span class="fa fa-archive"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But If i remove the datatable class on my table, (from                                 
 to 
), the orderBy worked.

[image]

But without the class of datable, the sort, search bar, and pagination will also removed which leaves a simple table

Comment: If your Laravel query is working as expected, then you should show us the code which consumes `$jobs`.

Comment: Did you mean the blade where i put the $jobs?

Comment: Please give code of your view(blade) file.

Comment: And where's the javascript for the datatable?

Comment: @linuxartisan I put it on the class of the table (class="table datatable table-hover")

Comment: But you have to initialize the datatables from javascript. It must be somewhere.

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril remove datatable default ordering,,BTW what is your datatable version?

Comment: @Sohel0415 I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril what have you tried? put your full view content and what is the datatable version you are using?

Comment: I tried this code and my datatable version is 1.10.13
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#jobTable').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
    });
})

I also tried the "ordering": false and no luck

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril in that case below Druv's answer should work

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril just add this line `destroy: true,` before this line `"ordering": false` on Druv's answer, it seems you have initialise your datatables before

Comment: @Sohel0415 Same. I just notice something though. Every time i reload my page, The table will get my data with orderBy, WITHOUT sort, search bar, and pagination. After that, It'll load the datatable itself. WITH sort, search bar and pagination and it'll shuffle my data.

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril first you should find out where is your datatable initialisation? Because i have gone through similar kind of problems yesterday and find out it was the initialisations that cause the problems.

Comment: @Sohel0415 It seems that I didn't initialize the datatable. I put it on my custom script and it finally worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @JiromesAngelRoncalBaril that's great work and thank you too

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Datatable and disable ordering in the table:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. noted that i put datatable in the class of the table. Is it because of that?